# Declarar el nombre de una variable en un For

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Como se podria en Js declarar variables nombradas con el valor de {i} del for;
Es decir

```
for(let i = 0; i<4; i++){
  const `variable ${i}` = i; 
}
```

y así quede declarado 3 constantes;

```
const variable1 = "1";
const variable2 = "2";
```

Comment: Hola ALR. ¿La idea sería implementar como en PHP variable variables? ¿Tiene que ser si o si `const`? ¿El contexto/scope es relevante?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si ... pero no

Puedes crearlas usado [`eval( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), pero **no** las puedes crear como `const`. El motivo es muy sencillo, al estar dentro de un `for( )`, si las creas como `const`, su ámbito será **dentro** de ese `for( )`.

Si quieres acceder a ellas desde fuera del `for( )`, tendrás que crearlas como `var`:

```js
function test( ) {
    for( let i = 0; i < 4; ++i ) {
        eval( `var i${i} = ${i};` );
    }

    console.log( i0 );
    console.log( i1 );
    console.log( i2 );
    console.log( i3 );
}

test( );
```

Por cierto, **NO USES `EVAL`**, es una inmensa fuente de problemas. Utiliza mejor `arrays`, atributos en objetos, o cualquier otro método.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar arrays para ello:

```js
const variables={};
for (let i=0;i<100;i++){
  variables["name_var_"+i]=i*100;
  variables[i]=i/100;
}
console.log("La variable name_var_1 vale: "+variables["name_var_1"]);
console.log("La variable 1 vale: "+variables["1"]);
console.log("La variable name_var_10 vale: "+variables.name_var_10);
```

Lo que realice fue crear un array clave/valor, donde almacenare las variables nuevas. Después dentro del bucle use el indice para crear nuevas variables.

En JS cada indice se puede usar como si fuera un atributo de una clase. Lo que significa que puedo hacer esto: `variables.name_var_1`, pero no esto: `variables.1`. Esto se debe a que en JavaScript no se pueden declarar variables que empiecen en números o que solo sea números.

> Nota: Digo variable pero realmente son nuevos indices.